# "Must have" tools for managing arbitrary *nix daemons and their activities

Tags: unix, monitoring, log-files, daemon

What tools do you advise for managing running daemons? This includes:

1. Load monitoring: renice a daemon when it slows down the whole server
2. Keeping alive: restart it when it's not functional. Maybe, connectivity checks?
3. Any advanced log processing/rotation/parsing tools?
4. Handy error notifications: e-mail, icq, jabber, ...
5. Realtime monitoring: munin || nagios, for sure! :) Maybe there's something else nice enough to be used?
6. ... other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Load monitoring: renice a daemon when it slows down the whole server
>    Keeping alive: restart it when it's not functional. Maybe, connectivity
>   checks?

Nagios can do both of these tasks with [event handlers](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/eventhandlers.html), for the renice though, I might rather have that run on its own because checks via something like ssh could timeout if the server is under load.  Ideally, the daemon has its own controls to prevent this from happening, ie 'Max Connections'.

```
Any advanced log processing/rotation/parsing tools?
```

I like logrotate for log rotation, it is pretty standard.  For processing, I like Splunk if you can either afford it, or don't need the features the paid version offers.

```
Handy error notifications: e-mail, icq, jabber, ...
```

To add to your list, Lots of people like text (SMS) Messages.

Comment: Nice, thanks! 
'MaxConnections' is okay, but sometimes some user launches one connection to a script that takes 100% CPU :))
P.S. Actually, I wrote "SMS" first, but then thought it's too much :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Cfengine too. We've got it running on everything from Linux to AIX and Windows. It's open source, but there's a commercial version that can do some extra tricks for real lightweight monitoring.

Splunk is ok, but if you learn a little regular expression magic, there isn't much you can't do.